# lucene .net parser for filter and sorting

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

In our lucene .net based search (Lucene 4.8.0-beta00016) we save the generated query, the filter and the sorting in a custom text file.

e.g.:

```
"Query":"+name:*test*"
"Filter":"BooleanFilter(+type:project)"
"Sort":"<long: \"creationdate\">!"
```

We built a test tool, similiar to Luke and we want to execute this saved search there and run a programmatic search:

For the query I can use the QueryParser and get the corresponding query object, but there seems to be no parser for the filter and the sort.

```
var queryParsed = new QueryParser().Parse("+name:*test*");
var filter = ?
var sort = ?
indexSearcher.Search(queryParsed, filter?, 10000, sort?);
```

Is there any way I can parse the filter and sort strings to a Filter/Sort object ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever thought to serialize your custom file in a different way?

I'm guessing your file is generated by calling the `toString()` method of each object type. Something like the follow

```
"Query:" + queryObject.toString()
"Filter:" + filterObject.toString()
"Sort:" + sortObject.toString()
```

If you serialize your original query, filter, and sort .NET objects as binary strings, in your test tool, you should be able to re-create the original .NET objects.

Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/

Comment: Great idea thanks for contributing ! 
But I do need a string representation as input to be able to modify the filter and sorting values and test performance and search hits.

I ended up building a small UI with all filter and sorting criterias that our business application allows. Not as flexible but it works...